# Visual Studio SDK - custom designer, file type & T4 template?

Tags: visual-studio-sdk

a happy new year to all :)

I've been looking into the VS SDK lately, to achieve something that seemed like an entry-level thing to do, but proves to be .. elusive :P

I want to do a custom file type, let's call it .view. Its an Xml or JSON file, that gets created by a custom designer and solution item, produces the xml or json, and gets transformed into code using some template. More or less what you get for .aspx files for example.

Apparently, the SDK documentation didn't help much in providing guidance with that, more like a reference if you know what you 're doing ?

Is there a tutorial that someone knows, or some pointers on how to get started on this ?

Thanks a lot !!!
O:]

Answer (score 0):

Well, after digging around, I found an MS sample to start from,( here: https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/Editor_With_Toolbox ). That gets me to the point that I have a custom editor for a file type, 50% there.

Now I'm looking into SingleFileGenerators as a means to auto-generate code after I'm done editing the xml/json file, and produce C# code. I'll update this when I get it working if anyone is interested.

[ VS SDK Documentation is seriously out-of-date and confusing ]

Comment: Did you... Ever get it to work? Currently in the same boat wanting to create a visual designer for a json-based file format and it is _seriously_ out of date and confusing out there.